# Multi Vanity URL

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I don't think it is actually called a multi vanity url but that's what I'm calling until I learn it's real name.

So far I have used .htaccess to set up a vanity url. So now if I type
    http://example.com/Username

I can go onto that users profile.

My .htaccess looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /page.php?username=$1
```

But I now want to make it so that if i type in:
    http://example.com/Username/Friends
It'll show me that users friends.

I've tried doing this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /page.php?username=$1&action=$2
```

But that doesn't work.

I've also tried:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /page.php?username=$1&action=$1
```

Does anyone know how I can do this?

Comment: erroneously often called "Search engine friendly" URL

Comment: @Dagon oh right, thanx. Now i don't have to go through life calling it by the wrong name.

Comment: i kind of like yours however

Comment: @Dagon thanx, I thought it was the most logical thing to call it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you need to capture both in the path. You want a sub directory you need to add more to the RewriteRule.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ /page.php?username=$1&action=$2 [NC,QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ /page.php?username=$1 [NC,QSA,L]
```

This is your rules together.